# GCP instance : ping high latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Since 2019-12-12 18:00 GMT+8 , instance on asia-east1-b ping latency is higher than a & b

```
ping asia-east1-c inatance, latency  7ms
ping asia-east1-b instance, latency 283ms
```

how to contact gcp technology support to resolve this problem ?

Comment: For Google Cloud report issues here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 1):

If you notice this is a temporary problem related to cloud networking please check the [Google Cloud services status dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/)

They might already acknowledged the problem and working on fixing it, however you can always report problems in the services / infrastructure by contacting support. In your GCP project go to Help (the question mark icon in the top) > Contact Support.

You can find more information inside that page.

Comment: If you don't have a support plan you can also open a Public Issue with them (response times will be slower) https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list